# How to load file octet-stream 3d model in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I load model .glb to s3 services then I get url from s3 is `https://test-image-prevaa-123.s3.amazonaws.com/test/1626336255367.octet-stream`. How to load model from this url to three.js. I load from my code then the model not showing. I'm new for three.js. I got this error in console `Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0` I guess that after I uploaded .glb file to s3 services, file is change to .octet-stream. I'm not sure how to load .octet-stream to three.js. Thank for your suggestion. I'm not sure load .octet-stream model to three.js

**my code**

```
  const data = this
  const loaderFile = new THREE.FileLoader()
      loaderFile.load(newFile, async function (file) {
           const loader = new GLTFLoader()
           loader.parse(file, '', function (glb) {
               const mesh = glb.scene
               mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2)
               data.scene.add(mesh)
               data.animate(mesh)
            })
       })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load that url like any other -- it just returns the content of the GLTF file. However assuming "newFile" is the url you posted there are a couple things that need to change in your code.

If you'd like you use `FileLoader` you need to set the responseType to `arraybuffer` which is what GLTFLoader.parse expects (see the [GLTFLoader Docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=gltfloader#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader)):

```js
const data = this
const loaderFile = new THREE.FileLoader()

// added this line:
loaderFile.setResponseType( 'arraybuffer' )

loaderFile.load(newFile, async function (file) {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader()
    loader.parse(file, '', function (glb) {
        const mesh = glb.scene
        mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2)
        data.scene.add(mesh)
        data.animate(mesh)
    })
})
```

Alternatively you could skip using `FileLoader` entirely and use `GLTFLoader.load` directly:

```js
const data = this
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load(newFile, function (glb) {
    const mesh = glb.scene
    mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2)
    data.scene.add(mesh)
    data.animate(mesh)
})
```

Comment: Oh! Thank. I'm a little confused